# How do I add the SSL certificate I bought on dnsimple for a subdomain when I already have an SSL certificate for the root domain?

Tags: ssl, heroku, dnsimple

In Heroku Settings, the SSL is showing for www.example.com but there is no where for me to add an SSL certificate for subdomain.example.com.

In DNSimple instructions it says to install the certificate at the command prompt:

```
$ heroku certs:add subdomain_example_com.pem subdomain_example_com.key
```

This results in:

```
Resolving trust chain... done
 ▸    Potentially Destructive Action
 ▸    This command will change the certificate of endpoint *********-17151 from ⬢ afternoon-********-5203.

$ heroku certs

***********-17151  www.example.com, example.com  2018-01-29
```

How do I install this SSL certificate for the subdomai without messing with the existing SSL certificate for www.example.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one SSL certificate on Heroku, so if you want more subdomains than www, you need a wildcard SSL certificate.